# join type for comparing two rows

Tags: sql-server

Just can't seem to figure this out, although it seems rather simple.

```
Table: Attd (...short for Attendance)
Visit  Person  Status  Date
1      1       Member  2011-01-31  
2      1       Member  2011-02-05  
3      2       Member  2011-02-05  
4      3       Not     2011-01-07  
5      1       Not     2011-01-25  
6      1       Not     2011-01-20  
7      1       Not     2011-02-03
```

The data belongs to visits to a location by individuals, which includes if they had a membership (Status column).

How would you select visits that took place one week before someone became a member (Same person: Status=Not --> Status=Member)?  [Output row 5 above.]

For example, 
Person 2 became a member without visiting before, because they had no Status=Not before they joined.

Person 3 visited as a non-member and never came back.

And, person 1 visited as a non-member (Status=Not on 2011-01-25) and became a member within one week (Status=Member on 2011-01-31).

Preliminary work:
a.  Pretty sure the answer contains a self join
b.  The dateAdd function help satisfy the one week before condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this simple query:

```
SELECT t1.Person
FROM
  (SELECT *
   FROM attd
   WHERE status = 'member')T1
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT *
   FROM attd
   WHERE status = 'not')T2 ON T1.Person = T2.Person
WHERE datediff(dd,T2.Date,T1.Date)<=7
```

You can find a working example on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/91a5b/2).

Hope this helps you and feel free to contact me if you have any more questions.

Answer (score 0):

First use aggregation to calculate the member date for each person.  This is presumably the minimum date where there is a status of `'Member'`.  Then do a join back to the table to get earlier visits:

```
select *
from (select a.person, min(date) as MemberDate
      from Attendance a
      where status = 'Member'
      group by a.person
     ) m join
     Attendance aprev
     on m.person = aprev.person and
        datediff(d, aprev.date, MemberDate) <= 7 and
        aprev.status = 'Not';
```

Strictly speaking the last condition `'aprev.status = 'Not'` is unnecessary, because those are the only statuses before the member date.  However, I think it clarifies the intent of the query.